# Style extra content in ag-grid exportDataAsExcel

Tags: javascript, excel, export-to-excel, ag-grid-js

I'm using the ag-grid API to export a grid to Excel using the `exportDataAsExcel` method.
I want to add a line at the beginning and at the end and add a style to them (color, font, height).
I saw that there are the properties - `appendContent` and `prependContent` for adding rows beyond the existing grid, but I did not find a way to add style to them.
Is there any way to add style to such lines?

Many thanks